# xamarin forms xaml OnPlatform not working on bindings

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

```
    <cv:BindableComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Themes}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTheme}">
      <cv:BindableComboBox.Title>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"
            iOS="{Binding ThemePickerTitle}"
            Android="{Binding ThemePickerTitle}"/>
      </cv:BindableComboBox.Title>
    </cv:BindableComboBox>
```

so I have picker and I want to bind its Title to ThemePickerTitle property.
It works well if I write it as inline attrubute. But I dont want to have title on windows. So I write OnPlatform to have it only on Ios and Droid, but now it does compile.

Comment: I think typeArgument should be different, but I dont know what it should be

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Xaml you pasted suppose that the `OnPlatform` object is the target of the Binding to string, and then the OnPlatform returns the right `string` depending on the Platform.

Unfortunately, that doesn't work because `OnPlatform` is not a `BindableObject` and can't be the target of a `Binding`.

What make sense, is using this Xaml:

```xml
<cv:BindableComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Themes}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTheme}">
  <cv:BindableComboBox.Title>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="BindingBase"
        iOS="{Binding ThemePickerTitle}"
        Android="{Binding ThemePickerTitle}"/>
  </cv:BindableComboBox.Title>
</cv:BindableComboBox>
```

It means that the `OnPlatform` returns the right Binding (without evaluating it) depending on the platform. As of today (2017-01-24), this does not work in Xamarin.Forms, but the patch to fix that is ready and will land in one of the next version: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/709.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: This does work but visual studio is showing this annoying error: XLS0504 Property 'BackgroundColor' does not support values of type 'OnPlatform`1 (BindingBase)'